# Granting a role to a user on a replica set in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

Using Mongo commands, I can create and grant a role to a user on a UAT environment but not the Pre-Production environment, at least not permanently.  The difference between them?  UAT is a single DB, Pre-Production is a replica set.

After a few seconds the role "disappears" from the user.  If I run the commmand "show users", the role is visible for the user, when I run it again several seconds later, it "disappears".

Why is it disappearing, and how can I ensure the role is set permanently?

Comment: You tried it on the primary or on the secondary server?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create role and user on Primary node:

use products
db.grantRolesToUser(
   "accountUser01",
   [ "readWrite" , { role: "read", db: "stock" } ],
   { w: "majority" , wtimeout: 4000 }
)

Please make sure it creates successfully and it will stay.